How to rowSpan and allow drag per group in ag-grid angular
ngOninit() {}

  getMasterColumnDefs() {
    return [
      { 
        headerName: 'Step', field: 'positionSeq', pinned: 'left', rowDrag: true, rowSpan: this.rowSpan.bind(this)
      },
      { headerName: 'Student', field: 'studentId', width: 150 },
    ];
  }

  onGridReady(params: any) {
    this.gridApi = params.api;
    this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi; 

    const steps = this.form.steps;
    if (steps && steps.length > 0) {
      this.masterRowData = this.updateSteps(steps);
      console.log('Master Row Data: ',this.masterRowData);
      console.log(JSON.stringify(this.masterRowData));
    }
  }
  updateSteps(steps: any[]) {
    const uniquePositionSeq = new Set<string>(); 

    const updatedSteps = steps.map(item => {

        const positionSeq = item.step.toString();
        if (uniquePositionSeq.has(positionSeq)) {
            delete item.positionSeq;
        } else {
            uniquePositionSeq.add(positionSeq);
            item.positionSeq = positionSeq;
        }

        return item;
    });

    return updatedSteps;
  }

What I'm trying to do here is to rowspan the step per position.
here's what I tried
const rowSpan = (params) => {
  const positionSeq = params.data ? params.data.positionSeq : undefined;
  const step = params.data ? params.data.step : undefined;
  const gridData = this.masterRowData || [];
  return gridData.filter((item) => item.step === Number(positionSeq)).length;
} 

But when I try to run it didn't rowSpan also the drag didn't work it should drag based on the positionSeq selected and it should not multiple drag based on positionSeq

